# Denormalization of a 1 to many schema

Tags: mysql, denormalization

I have a table structure in MySQL where I have the following structure:

> home_id, home_name, dateadded

I have another table called specs with the following structure:

> home_id, spec_key, spec_value

In it I can have entries like the following:

```
1, price, 500000
1, location, 90210
1, rooms, 3
1, washrooms, 3
1, furnished_basement, 0
2, location, 14410
2, garage_size, 3
2, price, 335000
```

For search purposes, I'd like to denormalize the above. The table (`denormalized_homes`) structure would look something like:

```
home_id, price, location, rooms, washroom, furnished_basement, garage_size, dateadded
```

As you can see from the above, a) not all entries have a value for all columns. b) The table structure is not conducive to `INSERT INTO`denormalized_homes`select * from`specs type queries. I also can't used stored procedures or triggers (host regulations).

The tactic I've taken so far is to insert home_id into the `denormalized_homes` table, and then run through each field in spec with something like the following query:

```
UPDATE `denormalized_homes` dh, specs s SET dh.price = s.spec_value WHERE dh.home_id = s.home_id AND s.spec_key = "price";
```

Creating a query for each possible column and then running them works. I'm just thinking there must be a better way,  is there?

Comment: I will, I always leave the question unanswered for a few days so that it doesn't stop people from answering if they have something else to offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO denormalized_homes ()

SELECT h.home_id,
       price.spec_value price,
       location.spec_value location,
       rooms.spec_value rooms,
       washroom.spec_value washroom,
       furnished_basement.spec_value furnished_basement,
       garage_size.spec_value garage_size,
       h.date_added

FROM   homes h

       LEFT JOIN specs price
       ON price.home_id = h.home_id and spec_key = 'price'

       LEFT JOIN specs location
       ON price.home_id = h.home_id and spec_key = 'location'       

       LEFT JOIN specs rooms
       ON price.home_id = h.home_id and spec_key = 'rooms'

       LEFT JOIN specs washroom
       ON price.home_id = h.home_id and spec_key = 'washroom'

       LEFT JOIN specs furnished_basement
       ON price.home_id = h.home_id and spec_key = 'furnished_basement'

       LEFT JOIN specs garage_size
       ON price.home_id = h.home_id and spec_key = 'garage_size'
```

Comment: Any specs that don't exist will just have a null value.